# Which tags do we want for data quality questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking for a tag for data quality related questions, I didn't get any results in the tag auto-complete. I therefore introduced a new "data-quality" tag.

Now, I realize that there is a "qa-qc" tag. In my opinion, using these abbreviations makes it difficult to discover the tag in the tag auto-complete field.

For me, I was looking for a tag name containing "quality" ...

Should we simply set up "data-quality" to be a synonym for "qa-qc"?

https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/qa-qc/synonyms

Comment: this is a good idea.as you i am searching a tag name containing "quality" too...

Comment: I would never have guessed that's what qa-qc meant

Answer (score 3):

I think `data-quality` should be the master, and `qa-qc` the synonym.

Answer (score 2):

`quality` should definitely be spelled out. However `quality-control` or `quality-assurance` could be but is not necessarily `data-quality`.

For instance *"are the labels on this map in the right place?"* is about quality assurance, while *"are the values in the [Name] attribute field correct?"* is about data quality.

To my mind quality-assurance encompasses data-quality, and would make that the master. So:

`quality-assurance` == `quality-control`, `data-quality`, `qa-qc`